# Get value of Output Parameter from stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the output parameter from the stored procedure wrote by my Database admin. Here is the stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sb_AddStudent]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @FirstName varchar(25),
    @LastName varchar(25),
    @Address varchar(300),
    @SID int output
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO StudentMaster(EntryDate, FirstName, LastName)
        VALUES (getdate(), @FirstName , @LastName);
        IF @@ERROR <> 0
            GOTO ErrorHandler;

        SELECT @SID= max(SID) 
        FROM StudentMaster

COMMIT TRANSACTION
    RETURN 0;


    -- if there is an error after any insert/update statement, it will go here --
    ErrorHandler:
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN @@error;             
END
```

Here is my code behind in vb.net. I am using Entity Framework.

```
 Dim outputParameter As Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter = New Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("SID ", GetType(Integer))

db.sb_AddStudent(FirstName, LastNmae, Address, outputParameter)

dim SID = outputParameter.Value
```

i am not getting any error and data are saved into database but i dont know whats the right way to get the output  value from the stored procedure. Please suggest the best way to get the output parameter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting Stored procedure form EF and re-adding it to the project fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Stored Procedure, Create a complex and bind that output value like this in your logic:

```
    public List<CompOffModel> GetCompOffRecords(string searchKeyword, string orderBycolumn, string orderByDirection, int start, int length, string StartYearFrom, string EndYearTo, string ApprovedBy, string CreatedBy, string DateFrom, string DateTo, string Name, string Reason, string IsUsed, ref int totalcount, ref int searchCount)
    {
        ObjectParameter objCountParam = new ObjectParameter("outputParameterOfSqlProcedure", 0);
        ObjectParameter objSearchCountParam = new ObjectParameter("outputParameterOfSqlProcedure1", 0);
        List<CompOffModel> result = db.SP_CompOff(searchKeyword, orderBycolumn, orderByDirection, start, length, StartYearFrom, EndYearTo, ApprovedBy, CreatedBy, DateFrom, DateTo, Name, Reason, IsUsed, objCountParam, objSearchCountParam).Select(x => new CompOffModel()
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            Name = x.Name,
            ApprovedBy = x.Approved_By,
            CreatedByString = x.Created_By,
            Reason = x.Reason,
            Date = x.Date,
            IsUsed = x.IsUsed,
            NoofCompOff = x.NoOfCompOff
        }).ToList();

        totalcount = Convert.ToInt32(objCountParam.Value);
        searchCount = Convert.ToInt32(objSearchCountParam.Value);
        return result;
    }
```